CNN ValueError: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling
I am working on making a DL model to predict a value. Statement goes like: we have a
time vs A vs B vs C -- xls files ( multiple ones , present in Data named folder )
I want to predict A using using what were previous values of A, B, C. This ofc means when its the first prediction, we'll get N/A as we dont have older A to user.
Current I have this: ( Im really new doing all online searching here and there ):
def load_data(folder_path):
    data_frames = []
    for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if file_name.endswith('.xls'):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
            df = pd.read_excel(file_path)  # Assuming the data is in Excel format
            data_frames.append(df)
    return pd.concat(data_frames, ignore_index=True)

def preprocess_data(data):
    X = data[['S', 'A', 'T']]
    y = data['F']
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
    X_reshaped = X_scaled.reshape(X_scaled.shape[0], X_scaled.shape[1], 1)  # Reshape for CNN
    return X_reshaped, y, scaler


def build_cnn_model(input_shape):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=10, activation='relu', input_shape=(1, 1,3),))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1)) 
    return model



def train_and_predict_next_frequency(folder_path, current_scheduled, current_actual):
    data = load_data(folder_path)

    X, y, scaler = preprocess_data(data)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)  
    X_train_reshaped = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1)
    X_test_reshaped = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1)

    print(input_shape)
    model = build_cnn_model(input_shape)

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

    model.fit(X_train_reshaped, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32, verbose=1)

    mse = model.evaluate(X_test_reshaped, y_test, verbose=0)
    print("Mean Squared Error:", mse)

    scaled_input = scaler.transform([[current_scheduled, current_actual]])
    input_reshaped = scaled_input.reshape(1, 2, 1)  # Reshape for CNN
    next_frequency_scaled = model.predict(input_reshaped)
    next_frequency = scaler.inverse_transform(next_frequency_scaled.reshape(-1, 1))
    return next_frequency[0][0]



folder_path = "Data"  # Folder containing the Excel files
current_scheduled = 10
current_actual = 8
predicted_frequency = train_and_predict_next_frequency(folder_path, current_scheduled, current_actual)
print("Predicted Next Frequency:", predicted_frequency)

and I am getting this error here:
ValueError:  One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv1d_10.
Consider increasing the input size. Received input shape [None, 1, 1, 3] which would produce
output shape with a zero or negative value in a dimension.

predict A using using what were previous values of A, B, C. ( whats prev? , we got timeblock to tell that ).
I tried changing the layer functions but it didnt work. I want to achieve the above mentioned

What did the original title of this question mean?  The question title >should< give the reader some idea of what you are asking ... so that they can decide whether or not to spend their time reading it (and fixing it up for you!)  I still don't know what CNN refers to in this context.

@StephenC CNN is convolutional neural network, a very well known term in the field. The title is clear if you have domain knowledge
